How do move extracted contents of spring tool suite to /opt directory?
Here is the problem from terminal
blessingstone@blessingstone-hp-pavilion:~/Downloads$ sudo mv sts.4.24.0.RELEASE/ /opt/sts/
sudo: unable to resolve host blessingstone-hp-pavilion
mv: cannot stat 'sts.4.24.0.RELEASE/': No such file or directory


Are you sure it's sts.4.24.0.RELEASE and not sts-4.24.0.RELEASE?
